# WPF Control remove focus and hover effect (FocusVisualStyle?!)

Tags: wpf, focusvisualstyle

I am trying to remove the nasty looking effect on controls when hovering or focusing.
This seems not to work:

> FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}"

And this is what I got so far:

```
<ComboBox Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="#FFE87E00" FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}"/>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Look at the control template, you should be able to manipulate what occurs when visual states changes from there.

Comment: Thanks, I was trying with Styles and Setters but I am not really into it. Could you provide a small example? I really can not figure it out!