# To remove focus rectangle in WPFwithin a UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, styles, focus

I have a situation where I need to tab using `TabKey` from one control to another. The condition is that the focus should never go to control that does not have user inputs so only `Text`, `ComboBox`, `List DatePicker` but somehow the focus after 3 controls get the `Focus` to go to a dashed line `Rectangle` (Could be of a `Grid`, StackPanel, I have not been able to findout) around the control groups before it gets into the control. I have searched very thoroughly in Google and stack over flow for a solution but none seem to work.

Various solutions I tried:

1) Here I set `FocusVisualStyle` property to null right at start up for `Grid` and `StackPanels`. Created a new class:

```
<StackPanel views:FocusVisualTreeChanger.IsChanged="True" Name="parentStackPanel" Orientation="Vertical" Style="{DynamicResource key1}" FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}">

public class FocusVisualTreeChanger
{
    public static bool GetIsChanged(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(IsChangedProperty);
    }

    public static void SetIsChanged(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(IsChangedProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsChangedProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsChanged", typeof(bool), typeof(FocusVisualTreeChanger), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits, IsChangedCallback));

    private static void IsChangedCallback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (true.Equals(e.NewValue))
        {
            FrameworkContentElement contentElement = d as FrameworkContentElement;
            if (contentElement != null)
            {
                contentElement.FocusVisualStyle = null;
                return;
            }

            FrameworkElement element = d as FrameworkElement;
            if (element != null)
            {
                element.FocusVisualStyle = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Did not work.

I tried setting `FocusVisualStyle` property to *null* for only `Grid` and `StackPanel` seems to go through the codebehind if I put a break point but the focus rectangle does not go away:

```
<Grid Name="AppointmentGrid" Style="{DynamicResource key2}" FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}">

Style style = new Style { TargetType = typeof(Grid) };
style.Setters.Add(new Setter(Grid.FocusVisualStyleProperty, null));
style.Setters.Add(new Setter(Grid.FocusableProperty, false));
Application.Current.Resources["key2"] = style;
Application.Current.Resources["key3"] = style;
Application.Current.Resources["key4"] = style;
Style style1 = new Style { TargetType = typeof(StackPanel) };
style1.Setters.Add(new Setter(StackPanel.FocusVisualStyleProperty, null));
style1.Setters.Add(new Setter(StackPanel.FocusableProperty, false));
Application.Current.Resources["key1"] = style1;
```

Can anyone please help me out with a solution that I have not already tried. None in stackoverflow solutions seem to work. I also set Focusable=false just incase but that doesn't seem to help either.

I also read:

[Remove focus rectangle on a UserControl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/818566/remove-focus-rectangle-on-a-usercontrol)

[WPF Control remove focus and hover effect (FocusVisualStyle?!)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15783943/wpf-control-remove-focus-and-hover-effect-focusvisualstyle)

[WPF: Remove dotted border around focused item in styled listbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592665/wpf-remove-dotted-border-around-focused-item-in-styled-listbox)

This is what I think I am stuck at. A comment I found in one of the search [sites](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/141c8bfa-f152-4f8a-aca0-3c3b5440d183/globally-removing-focus-rectangle).

That's a great way to change the default value of a DP, but it will not help in situations where a control's style explicitly changes the property value.  Unfortunately, `FocusVisualStyle` is one such property.  More specifically, styles for controls like `Button`, `ComboBox`, `ListBox`, etc. tend to explicitly contain a Setter for the FocusVisualStyle property. This setter will override the default value that you establish by overriding the metadata.

Can someone suggest a solution that will work in my case. I have a User control

```
<UserControl 
          xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:csla="http://schemas.lhotka.net/4.2.0/xaml" 
          xmlns:input="clr-             
         FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}"
         Focusable="False"
         xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Input.Toolkit"
         mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="948"
         IsTabStop="False" 
         TabIndex="-1">

<StackPanel views:FocusVisualTreeChanger.IsChanged="True" Name="parentStackPanel" Orientation="Vertical" Style="{DynamicResource key1}" FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}"><Grid Name="AppointmentGrid" Style="{DynamicResource key2}" FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}">
```

Thanks
Dhiren

Comment: I have also had trouble in the past with focus for UserControls. I don't have a specific answer, but I found Snoop [link](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) to be a valuable resource. It shows what element has the current focus.